# jquery: Moving items from one list to another and collect multiple data from that list

Tags: php, jquery, html, select

I have two select control in my HTML form.

```
    <form name="frmMultiple" id="frmMultiple" method="get" action="MovingItemsFromList.php">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th align="left" valign="top">Select:</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left" valign="top">Selected:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <select id="cboCountryID" name="cboCountryID" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;" size="10">
                <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="3">America</option>
                <option value="3">Albania</option>
                <option value="4">Algeria</option>
                <option value="5">American samoa</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <input type="button" id="btnMoveRight" name="btnMoveRight" value=">>" />
            <input type="button" id="btnMoveLeft" name="btnMoveLeft" value="<<" />
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <select id="cboCountryIDSelected" name="cboCountryIDSelected" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;" size="10">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Show" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I can easily move data from one select control/combo box to another by using jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cboCountryID').dblclick(function(){return !$('#cboCountryID option:selected').appendTo('#cboCountryIDSelected');});
        $('#btnMoveRight').click(function(){return !$('#cboCountryID option:selected').appendTo('#cboCountryIDSelected');});

        $('#cboCountryIDSelected').dblclick(function(){return !$('#cboCountryIDSelected option:selected').appendTo('#cboCountryID');});
        $('#btnMoveLeft').click(function(){return !$('#cboCountryIDSelected option:selected').appendTo('#cboCountryID');});
    });
```

Problem is, I want to collect data from my second select control/combo box by using PHP.
If I use [] in control name, it stops moving data.
Can anyone kindly give me any solution?

Comment: Are you changing the id or the name? I changed the name and it works fine, see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0mp145yj/1/

Comment: You are welcome, I added an answer for reference, please mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only change the name, not the id to `cboCountryIDSelected[]`

```
<select id="cboCountryIDSelected" name="cboCountryIDSelected[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;" size="10"></select>
```